# Finding suitable value(s) n for the following Integral Equation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

For what values of $n$ does $$\int_0^1\ln(x^n+1)\ln(2-x^n)\, dx = 1$$

Progress: I tried using Differentiation under the Integral Sign but it didn't work out too well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:
**1)** The function $\ln(2-x^n)$ is defined for all $x\in [0,\,1]$ only if $n \geqslant 0.$
**2)**
$\displaystyle \ln(x^n+1)\ln(2-x^n) = \ln\left[\frac{3}{2} + \left(x^n - \frac{1}{2}  \right)  \right]\cdot \ln\left[\frac{3}{2} - \left(x^n - \frac{1}{2}  \right)  \right].$
After substitution $t = x^n - \frac{1}{2}, \quad 0\leqslant x \leqslant 1 \implies -\frac{1}{2} \leqslant t \leqslant \frac{1}{2},$ we have
$$\ln\left[\frac{3}{2} + \left(x^n - \frac{1}{2}  \right)  \right]\cdot \ln\left[\frac{3}{2} - \left(x^n - \frac{1}{2}  \right)  \right] = \ln\left(\frac{3}{2} + t \right) \cdot \ln\left(\frac{3}{2} - t \right) .$$
The function $f(t) = \ln\left(\frac{3}{2} + t \right) \cdot \ln\left(\frac{3}{2} - t \right) $ is an even function on $\left[-\frac{1}{2}, \, \frac{1}{2} \right]$ and 
$$\max\limits_{t\in \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \, \frac{1}{2} \right]} f(t) = f(0) = \ln^2{\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)}\approx 0.164401953893165.$$ 
Therefore,
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ln(x^n+1)\ln(2-x^n) \,dx = \int\limits_{0}^{1}\ln\left[\frac{3}{2} + \left(x^n - \frac{1}{2}  \right)  \right]\cdot \ln\left[\frac{3}{2} - \left(x^n - \frac{1}{2}  \right)  \right]\,dx \leqslant \\ \leqslant \cdot \ln^2{\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} \int\limits_{0}^{1}dx  = \ln^2{\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} < 1.$$
Thus, such $n$ that $$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ln(x^n+1)\ln(2-x^n)\, dx = 1,$$ does not exist.